# Call a range of dates from an API using Python

Tags: python, api, date, range

Currently writing a program using an API from MarketStack.com. This is for school, so I am still learning.

I am writing a stock prediction program using Python on PyCharm and I have written the connection between the program and the API without issues. So, I can certainly get the High, Name, Symbols, etc. What I am trying to do now is call a range of dates. The API says I can call up to 30 years of historical data, so I want to call all 30 years for a date that is entered by the user. Then the program will average the high on that date in order to give a trend prediction.

So, the problem I am having is calling more than one date. As I said, I want to call all 30 dates, and then I will do the math, etc.

Can someone help me call a range of dates? I tried installing Pandas and that wasn't being accepted by PyCharm for some reason.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests

# callouts for window size
HEIGHT = 650
WIDTH = 600


# function for response
def format_response(selected_stock):
try:
    name1 = selected_stock['data']['name']
    symbol1 = selected_stock['data']['symbol']
    high1 = selected_stock['data']['eod'][1]['high']

    final_str = 'Name: %s \nSymbol: %s \nEnd of Day ($ USD): %s' % (name1, symbol1, high1)
except:
    final_str = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'

return final_str


# function linking to API
def stock_data(entry):
params = {'access_key': 'xxx'}
response = requests.get('http://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/' + entry + '/' + 'eod', params=params)
selected_stock = response.json()

label2['text'] = format_response(selected_stock)


# function for response
def format_response2(stock_hist_data):
try:
    name = stock_hist_data['data']['name']
    symbol = stock_hist_data['data']['symbol']
    high = stock_hist_data['data']['eod'][1]['high']
    name3 = stock_hist_data['data']['name']
    symbol3 = stock_hist_data['data']['symbol']
    high3 = stock_hist_data['data']['eod'][1]['high']

    final_str2 = 'Name: %s \nSymbol: %s \nEnd of Day ($ USD): %s' % (name, symbol, high)
    final_str3 = '\nName: %s \nSymbol: %s \nEnd of Day ($ USD): %s' % (name3, symbol3, high3)
except:
    final_str2 = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'
    final_str3 = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'

return final_str2 + final_str3


# function for response in lower window
def stock_hist_data(entry2):
params2 = {'access_key': 'xxx'}
response2 = requests.get('http://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/' + entry2 + '/' + 'eod', params=params2)
hist_data = response2.json()

label4['text'] = format_response2(hist_data)
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean "call a range" or "all 30 years for a date". Does the API support this? Does it give all 30 years at once? Can you show your code so far? When stock data says they have 30 years, it typically means the past 30 years from today, not before any given date

Comment: So, calling the API information, I am still learning this and so my terminology might be a little off, sorry.

Comment: Just figured out how to put the code into my question....so I have the top function calling the HIGH, NAME, and SYMBOL

Comment: The bottom function is currently a place holder to call for dates. I would send a request to the API using                                                            
    http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod
    ? access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
    & symbols = AAPL
    & date_from = 2019-01-01
    & date_to = 2019-02-01                                                                                                       This, however, is not using Python syntax and that is the first issue. the next issue would be to select a RANGE of dates from the API.

Comment: You already have `access_key` in `params`, so where does the API say to add the rest of that data? For example, you have `/tickers' + entry`, so is entry the symbol? Now, where do the date parameters need to go? Note: We shouldn't be responsible for reading the API docs for you, and without that context, we couldn't answer how you use those dates

Comment: For example, if you did add a date into the params, what happens?

Comment: When i add a date into the params it errors as if not knowing what to do with it. I thought about adding the 'import DateTime' , but that didn't change the error for me. The error itself is not actually telling me what is wrong, just pointing out the fact it doesn't understand the line of code. Which is confusing. The 'entry' is for the user to enter the symbol of the stock they want to access. so, the user enters

Comment: WIFI and the URL adds the WIFI in that position, then sends the request. I get the results back that I am asking for. I can ask for a single date, but I need help asking for a range of dates. Not sure how to do that using an API.